# Como puedo formatear numero con miles (puntos) y poder agregar una coma en JS

Tags: javascript

tengo un input para ingresar el valor. El código me formatea el número por ej: 10000 así 10.000 pero no me permite agregar una coma por ejemplo: 10.000,10

```
const number = document.querySelector('#oportunidaddetalle-precio');

function formatNumber (n) {

  n = String(n).replace(/\D/g, "");

  return n === '' ? n : Number(n).toLocaleString();

}

number.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const element = e.target;

  const value = element.value;
  element.value = formatNumber(value);


});
```

Comment: ¿quieres que cuando cambie el valor del `input` este tenga un formato concreto? Lo que no queda claro es porqué no puedes poner 10.000,10 si ya te lo hace automáticamente si pones un número decimal..

Comment: @dteterevkov un ejemplo podría ser como la calculadora en el pc, uno escribe los número y automáticamente pone los separadores de miles con puntos pero si deseo tambien puedo agregar una coma mediante el teclado.

Answer (score 1):

**Que tal compañero, quizá esto te ayude o te de alguna idea de como lograrlo!. Este es un código similar al number_format de PHP**

```js
function number_format_js(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_point) {

        if (number == null || !isFinite(number)) {
            throw new TypeError("number is not valid");
        }

        if (!decimals) {
            var len = number.toString().split('.').length;
            decimals = len > 1 ? len : 0;
        }

        if (!dec_point) {
            dec_point = '.';
        }

        if (!thousands_point) {
            thousands_point = ',';
        }

        number = parseFloat(number).toFixed(decimals);

        number = number.replace(".", dec_point);

        var splitNum = number.split(dec_point);
        splitNum[0] = splitNum[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousands_point);
        number = splitNum.join(dec_point);

        return number;
    }
    
    var valueBalance = number_format_js('10000',2,',','.');    
    alert(valueBalance);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo probe y lo que hace es que cuando tiene el valor listo lo formatea y le agrega los decimales, pero yo ingreso valores desde un input y al instante debe empezar a formatear en miles con puntos 1.000 (esto lo hago) y además permitir agregar una coma desde el teclado al final (esto no me sale), como en las calculadoras uno ingresa solo los números y automático lo formatea y si necesito permite agregar la coma.

Comment: Ok vale. Bueno, te propongo lo siguiente: Se me ocurre que dentro del proceso en el que haces el formateo de los miles, guardes ese número en una variable y lo conviertas a string. Después recorre esa string con el número digitado y valida si se tecleó una coma en el teclado, si existe la coma, ahora obtén los últimos dos dígitos del número y concaténalos a la string original. Mas o menos así se me ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function format( num ) {
       // verificamos si existe el signo "-", si está, lo almacenamos en la variable 
       // **signo** y acortamos la cadena recibida
    let signo = "";
    let posSigno = num.indexOf( "-" );
    if( posSigno != -1 ) {
        signo = "-";
        num = num.substring( 1 );             
    }

       // verificamos si hay un ".", si no hay, instanciamos **aux** con ",00"
       // si hay y está a "1" del fin, lo hacemos con el último número más "0"
       // y le quitamos los decimales a **num**
       // en otro caso, instanciamos **aux** con los valores contenidos después 
       // del punto, y acortamos **num** 
    let aux = "";
    let pos = num.indexOf( "." );
    if( pos == -1 ) {
        aux = ",00";
    }
    else if( pos == num.length() -2 ) {
        aux = "," + num.substring( pos + 1 ) + "0";
        num = num.substring( 0, pos );
    }
    else {
        aux = "," + num.substring( pos + 1 );  
        num = num.substring( 0, pos );
    }

    let contador = 1;
    let salida = "";

       // recorremos el array en sentido inverso y vamos agregando adelante de 
       // lo ya contenido, el valor encontrado en esa posición, si el contador
       // es multiplo de "3", agregamos un "."
    for( let i = num.length -1; i > -1; i-- ) {
        salida = num.substring( i, i + 1 ) + salida;
        if( contador  % 3 == 0 ) { 
            salida = "." + salida;
        }
        contador ++;
    }

       // retornamos la concatenación del signo, los enteros y los decimales
    return signo + salida + aux;
}
console.log( format( "-12000" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar primero la funcion toFixed de Number y luego modificar el punto por la coma y finalmente añadir los puntos de los miles como hace Luis Fernando en la otra respuesta.

```
function formatear (inputNumber){
   const decimal = Number(inputNumber.replace(",", ".")).toFixed(2); //cambiamos la "," por el "." por si introduce un string con ","
   const formated = decimal.replace(".",",").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
   return formated;
}

console.log(formatear("1233234,8"))
```